# Match words with a specific letter and not another letter

Tags: regex, letter

I have a couple of strings and want only words with letter `o` and not word with letter `u`.

For example:

- `hello`
- `our`
- `hey`
- `owner`
- `udnwedfo`

So it should work on the word `hello` and `owner`.

I have tried something like

```
([^u])?([o])?([^u])
```

But so far it did'nt work.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/uCSnXx/1

Comment: Please always mention tool/lang you're using along with a regex question (function scope differs). Depending on what you use, e.g. [`\b[a-tv-z]*o[a-tv-z]*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/5JkXyg/1) (use in casless mode / with `i`-flag)